# dcexec login failure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, security, authentication, data-collection

I have a SQL Server 2008 R2 instance that I have been trying to get Data Collection setup on. I get everything setup, but there is no data that gets uploaded. I've traced the root of the problem to be a failure in the SQL Agent jobs where it calls dcexec.

Isolating that out, I can reproduce the issue by running:

```
& "D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn\dcexec.exe" -c -s 1 -i "localhost\MSSQLSERVER" -m 1
```

I run the above command from a PowerShell window that I've opened with **RunAs Administrator**. The account I am running the above with is a domain account that is a **local administrator** on the server. In addition, the account also has the **sysadmin** role on the SQL instance.

The error that I get is:

```
SSIS error. Component name: GenerateTSQLPackageTask, Code: -1073548540, 
Subcomponent: Generate T-SQL Package Task, 
Description: An error occurred with the following error message: 
"An error occurred while verifying the result set schema against the output table schema. 
The data collector cannot connect to the management data warehouse. : Login failed.
The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication."..

The master package exited with error, previous error messages should explain the cause.
```

That is the same error I see in the history on the SQL Server Agent job.

Note that if I execute dcexec with a bad instance name, such as:

```
& "D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn\dcexec.exe" -c -s 1 -i "localhost\MSSQLSERVER1" -m 1
```

Then, as expected, I get a different error:

```
Failed to get the SQL server instance id from the given instance name.
```

Any ideas on how to successfully login to the SQL instance with dcexec?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved with some hints from:

- [Performance Data Collector in 2008](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d1fbf5e5-387b-488b-b813-75a8c0b01ea5/performance-data-collector-in-2008)
- [Data Collector - Cannot Find Database](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ar-SA/e9ed6705-0731-424e-9af2-2c84bf5baff8/data-collector-cannot-find-database)

When I setup Data Collection I did the following:

**Setup**

```
SSMS > serverA
Management > Data Collection
Configure Management Data Warehouse
Next
 > Check: Create or upgrade a management data warehouse
Next
New
 > Database name: DBA_MDW
OK
 > Server name: serverA.company.com
 > Database name: DBA_MDW
Next
New Login
 > Login name: DOMAIN\SQLmdw
OK
 > Check: mdw_admin
 > Check: mdw_reader
 > Check: mdw_writer
Next
Finish
Close
```

**Configuration**

```
Configure Management Data Warehouse
Next
 > Check: Set up data collection
Next
 > Server name: serverA.company.com
 > Database name: DBA_MDW
 > Cache directory:
Next
Finish
Close
```

To uninstall Data Collection, I used the script from [Remove associated data collector jobs](https://web.archive.org/web/20160219221441/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/sqlagent/archive/2011/07/22/remove-associated-data-collector-jobs.aspx). I then followed the above setup and configuration steps, but this time under the configuration step I simply put **serverA** instead of **serverA.company.com**. That seems to have made all the difference and I'm now collecting data.